# How to filter out multiple values of a particular set

Tags: sql, select

In this example, how do I filter out 10 year old males?  I don't want to filter out all males nor all 10 year olds.  Also I don't want to specify the list of attributes that I want to filter for, just attributes I want to filter out!

Sample data and table:

```
sqlite> create table person ( age int, gender char(1), name varchar(10));
sqlite> insert into person values (10,'f','Anoushka');
sqlite> insert into person values (10,'m','James');
sqlite> insert into person values (30,'f','Mei');
sqlite> insert into person values (30,'m','Ahmed');
```

I used this select which returns the data I want, but is there a better way?

```
sqlite> select *
   ...> from person
   ...> where age || gender != '10m';
10|f|Anoushka
30|f|Mei
30|m|Ahmed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select *
from person
where age != '10'
or gender != 'm';
```

Comment: That was quick.  I will mark as the answer in 11 minutes.  LOL

Answer (score 0):

I did find another way.  You just need to us `or` logic, which I seldom use, but it comes in handy.

```
sqlite> select *
   ...> from person
   ...> where (age != 10 or gender != 'm');
10|f|Anoushka
30|f|Mei
30|m|Ahmed
```

Another way to exclude 10 year old males is to simply `not` that filter.  This option is easier to read for me.

```
sqlite> select *
   ...> from person
   ...> where not (age = 10 and gender = 'm');
10|f|Anoushka
30|f|Mei
30|m|Ahmed
```

See also [De Morgan's Laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws):  *"not (A and B)" is the same as "(not A) or (not B)"*

Comment: well this is the exact same answer as posted by StevieG above

Comment: Yup.  We posted at almost the exact same time.  I meant to hit **'answer my own question'**, but I was hasty and hit the wrong button.